# Dynamic task dependency based on a value of a property

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, build

I need to create a plugin which would provide an interactive task, invoked like this:

```
> ./gradlew analyzeSomething --configuration compileClasspath
```

Here the `--configuration` argument is supposed to be the name of a configuration in the project which is used for the analysis.

However, this analysis requires some data computed from the configuration, which might be expensive. Therefore, I'd like to cache this data, but, naturally, in a way which would result in cache invalidation in case contents of the configuration change (e.g. a dependency is added by the user). Ideally I'd take advantage of the built-in Gradle task dependencies mechanisms, which would track task dependencies and allow not to run a computation unless its input has changed.

This is the solution I came up with, but it does not work. First, declare two properties in the `AnalyzeSomething` class:

```
abstract class AnalyzeSomethingTask : DefaultTask() {
    @get:Internal
    @get:Option(option = "configuration", description = "Configuration")
    abstract val configuration: Property<String>

    @get:Internal
    abstract val dataCacheFile: RegularFileProperty
}
```

Second, create a task rule to instantiate tasks performing the expensive computation:

```
abstract class PrecomputeTask : DefaultTask() {
    @get:InputFiles
    abstract val classpath: ConfigurableFileCollection

    @get:OutputFile
    abstract val outputFile: RegularFileProperty
}

project.tasks.addRule("Pattern precompute<Configuration>") {
    val taskName = this
    if (taskName.startsWith("precompute")) {
        val configurationName = taskName.removePrefix("precompute").decapitalize()
        val configuration = project.configurations.getByName(configurationName)
        project.tasks.register<PrecomputeTask>(taskName) {
            classpath.from(configuration)
            outputFile.set(temporaryDir.resolve("data.txt"))
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, create the `analyzeSomething` task and in the `project.afterEvalute` block (so all the properties of the task are already set, including those on the command line) set up a dependency between `analyzeSomething` and one of the rule-generated tasks:

```
val analyzeSomething = project.tasks.register<AnalyzeSomethingTask>("analyzeSomething")
project.afterEvaluate {
    analyzeSomething.configure {
        val precomputeTaskName = "precompute" + configuration.get().capitalize()
        dataCacheFile.set(
            project.tasks.named<PrecomputeTask>(precomputeTaskName)
                .flatMap { it.outputFile }
        )
    }
}
```

This approach, however, does not work, because apparently the `register()` and any other collection configuration methods cannot be called at whatever point they are called in such setup:

```
> ./gradlew analyzeSomething --configuration runtimeClasspath
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':analyzeSomething'.
...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractMutationGuard$IllegalMutationException: DefaultTaskContainer#create(String, Class, Action) on task set cannot be executed in the current context.
```

So my question is, is there a way to set up task dependencies based on a property name, and if not, what would be a better way to do what I what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, this approach works once I get rid of `project.afterEvaluate`, with some moderately complex providers shuffling:

```
// instead of
val analyzeSomething = project.tasks.register<AnalyzeSomethingTask>("analyzeSomething")
project.afterEvaluate {
    analyzeSomething.configure {
        val precomputeTaskName = "precompute" + configuration.get().capitalize()
        dataCacheFile.set(
            project.tasks.named<PrecomputeTask>(precomputeTaskName)
                .flatMap { it.outputFile }
        )
    }
}

// do this

project.tasks.register<AnalyzeSomethingTask>("analyzeSomething") {
    dataCacheFile.set(
        configuration.flatMap { c ->
            val precomputeTaskName = "precompute" + c.capitalize()
            project.tasks.named<PrecomputeTask>(precomputeTaskName)
                .flatMap { it.outputFile }
        }
    )
}
```

I'm really curious why this approach works compared to the `project.afterEvaluate`-based one, but it *does* seem to work correctly, as it results in the proper `precompute*` task being added to the task graph, and its output being used for the analysis.